# How to use DataGrip for personal purposes?

Tags: sql, datagrip

I'm trying to learn SQL and for that I've downloaded DataGrip to practise.
But I can't create a database because I have no server connection. I don't want to connect to corporate services.
Is that possible to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Have you read https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/mysql.html You can use "localhost" as the server hostname, and use it to connect to a local instance of MySQL Community Edition that you run on your workstation. I suppose you can use other brands of SQL database too (links are in the sidebar of that page I linked to), but I use MySQL.

Comment: @BillKarwin thank you. It worked! 
I did read the link, I just didn't know which instance to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest SQLite: you don't need any server.

In DataGrip:

- In Database Explorer press + | Data Source | SQLite
- Download missing drivers
- Click 'Test Connection'
- Ok

Voila! You have your empty database where you can create schemas, tables etc.

[image]